# LESS: Netbeans 8.0 doesn't use `Compiler options` when configuring `CSS Preprocessor`

Tags: netbeans, less

I've successfully configured automatic compilation of LESS on my project and it works ok, but I wanted to add line numbers to the output files and here is what I got:

---

> <kbd>**NetBeans 8.0**</kbd> > <kbd>Options</kbd> > <kbd>Miscellaneous</kbd>

- <kbd>Less path | input field |</kbd>: `/usr/bin/lessc`
- Both checkboxes under the LESS section are checked.

> <kbd>Project properties</kbd> > <kbd>CSS Preprocessors</kbd> > <kbd>LESS |tab|</kbd>

- <kbd>Compile LESS Files on Save [checkbox]</kbd>: **checked**
- <kbd>Input (path)</kbd> <kbd>Output (path)</kbd>: `/less` `/css`
- <kbd>Compiler Options | input field |</kbd>: `--clean-css --line-numbers=comments`

---

But at the output I receive CSS **like** I'm **compiling without any options**.

It does compile and its Ok, but any option seems to be ignored.

But if I'm **using manually, the same compiler from the command line** with the same options **it does what it should** and compiles with line numbers and clean CSS.

Comment: What is the content of output window in NetBeans called ```LESS (compile)``` ? It should print the command used for compiling.

Comment: @ladar The strange thing about it (_forgot to mention_) that `Output` window itself shows nothing.

Comment: Are you sure it's being compiled? :) Anyway, go to Window->Output to open it

Comment: @ladar I'm sure :) bec. I can watch this process, when I change LESS and in a few moments changes appear at the output `.css`. And `Output` window is docked, so I'm watching it most of the time. I'm on **Ubuntu 14.04** + **Netbeans 8.0**.

Comment: And what do you have in the ```LESS (compile)``` tab? It works fine for me (same OS, same NetBeans)

Comment: @ladar I suppose that this tab should appear under `Output` window? If so - I have nothing there, any tab. When I'm saving LESS it writes in kinda popup closer to the bottom of the screen `style.less saved.` and that's it. And somewhere in background it works. I will check on another machine today. All results will post here.

Comment: @ladar Posted an answer. Problem was very funny. I figured it out washing my head in the morning ))). Thanks for attention!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, actually the problem was next ... framework compiler was overwriting CSS when generating assets.

I'm using *Symfony2*. And there is **already configured `*.less` compilation**, what I completely forgot asking my question.

*Netbeans* compiles LESS on it's own and *Symfony* uses it's own compiler and filters to organize CSS for the project. Thus, the *framework compiler should be configured* in my case to get desired result.

Maybe this situation will help someone to figure out similar problem.